# How do I light an unlit torch?

Tags: neo-scavenger

In NEO Scavenger I have crafted a quality torch (unlit) and now I want to light it but I can't work out how.  I've tried combining it with my campfire or the lighter but it just reverses the torch into wood and kindling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to Select It from the "known recipes" tab for it to work,, and you have to have a flame source and a torch,, if you just put the ingredients in the box with no recipe selection it just breaks the torch apart...

Answer (score 2):

Were there any orange arrow buttons at the top right corner of the crafting output area? Sometimes, when multiple possibilities are available, you'll only see the first one, and have to click those arrows to see other possible outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

According to the wiki:

```
Both types can be ignited with cigarette lighter or directly from a campfire or another torch.
```

I think combining the lighter and the torch should be enough, considering the 'recipe' for a lit torch is an unlit torch and a flame source.
[source](http://neoscavenger.wikia.com/wiki/Torches)